# Java 7 (Update 7 and 9) on Mac OSX - Applet printing tiny fonts

Tags: java, applet

As of Java 7, when you go to print from an Applet the fonts are no longer readable (super tiny). A preview of the same on content on the screen is not an issue only show a font issue when you print the contents.

To see this failure in action you can test using this page:

https://www.peernet.com/PEERNETReportsServer3/ademos.htm

On this page,:

1. press the preview button to show the page to be printed
2. press the 'Print...' button, print to any printer and you see the textual information is just printed as dashes (super tiny font).

Any suggestions on how to correct Java 7 printing from applets.

BTW: This is a problem on Lion and Mountain Lion with Java 7, it works OK from a full Java application as well as applet running in Windows and OSX with Java 6

Answer (score 0):

This could be something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827868/why-are-fonts-in-java-1-7-different-to-1-6), although in this case it's Oracle on mac vs. oracle on Windows. Sounds like the rendering for Java 7 is implemented differently and you're getting smaller fonts.